# Bluetooth scanning is disabled

Tags: bluetooth

I bought an android car head. I can search and pair my phone with it, but form the unit itself cant search for the devices and it always empty list. Is there a way to enable scanning from the unit it seems it was disabled by the admin?

Answer (score 0):

In settings , under connections wifi,turn off wifi there will be a option underneath about scanning  you can select Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scanning in the background on or off